# Как открыть новое окно на JS, если adblock блокирует?

Tags: javascript, popup

нужно чтобы открывалось новое окно со списком элементов из localStorage при нажатии на кнопку. Проблема в том, что adblock это блокирует. Можно ли как-то добиться подобного поведения по-другому?

```
 showList.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) == null){
            alert ("Список пустой");
            return;
        }
 
        function urlSiteCrop(url) {
            let output = url.replace(/^/, `"`).replace(/$/, `",`);
            return output;
        };
        
        let itemsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
 
        let output = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
            output[i] = urlSiteCrop(itemsArray[i]) + ("<br>");
        }
 
        window().open.document.write(output.join(""));
    })
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что именно adBlock, а не браузер?

Comment: `window().open.document.write` — доктор, это что было?

Comment: Уверен, без adblock норм. Я пишу для себя userscript с около нулевым опытом, так что тут главное, чтобы работало.

Comment: window.open().document.write(....